# Java FX UI blocked by ExecutorService

Tags: javafx

I have a problem how to correctly update Java FX UI. I'm moving from Swing to FX for the first time and also ExecutorService. Problem is I need to show gif file and update progress bar during code execution but instead I get white screen with mouse loading icon. The gif and progressbar are eventually showed but after finishing this for cycle: `for (int i = 0; i < futures.size(); i++)`

I thought that running tasks in `ExecutorService` is in separate thread and using `Platform.runLater` for progressbar will separate UI from long running code in `ExecutorService`. Can you give me some explanation what is going on please?

**Controller.java:**

```
public void initialize() {
        ivGif.setImage(new Image(Main.class.getResourceAsStream("/test/loading.gif")));
}


public void synchronizeFiles() {   
     Platform.runLater(() -> pbDownloading.setVisible(true));  
     ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);    
     ArrayList<Future<Boolean>> futures = new ArrayList<>();

     File localFile = new File(simplified code here);

     Future<Boolean> f = pool.submit(new DownloadTask(new URL(simplified code here), localFile));
     futures.add(f);

     for (int i = 0; i < futures.size(); i++) {
         final int position = i;
         Platform.runLater(() -> {
             pbDownloading.setProgress(position / (double) futures.size());                    
         });

         if (!futures.get(i).get(600, TimeUnit.SECONDS)) {
             System.out.println("ShutdownNow");
             pool.shutdownNow();
            }
     }

}
```

**DownloadTask.java:**

```
public class DownloadTask implements Callable<Boolean> {

protected Category cat = Category.getInstance(DownloadTask.class.getName());

private URL fileURL;
private File toPath;

public DownloadTask(URL fileURL, File toPath) {
    this.fileURL = fileURL;
    this.toPath = toPath;
}

private void downloadFile(URL fileURL, File toPath) throws IOException {
    ReadableByteChannel readableByteChannel = Channels.newChannel(fileURL.openStream());
    if (!toPath.getParentFile().exists()) {
        if (!toPath.getParentFile().mkdirs()) throw new IOException("Unable to create parent dirs for file: "+toPath.getAbsolutePath());
    }
    FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(toPath);
    fileOutputStream.getChannel().transferFrom(readableByteChannel, 0, Long.MAX_VALUE);

    URLConnection urlConnection = fileURL.openConnection();
    if (!toPath.setLastModified(urlConnection.getLastModified())) cat.error("Unable to write modified time stamp for file: "+toPath.getAbsolutePath());
}

@Override
public Boolean call() {
    try {
        downloadFile(fileURL, toPath);
    } catch (IOException e){
        System.out.println(e);
        cat.error(e, e);
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
}
```

Thank you

**EDIT:** I didn't realize that the main class is running from FX Application Thread. So I had reverse threads and just applied the `new thread (() -> {...}).Start();` in the main class in the start method and it's ok.

Comment: Have you seen [Concurrency in JavaFX](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/interoperability-tutorial/concurrency.htm)?

Comment: [mcve] please ..

Comment: you might consider answering your own question - if you think it would be helpful to future readers